# Derived control using base class Style without XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, code-behind, basedon

I am making some wrapper classes which encapsulate the setup details of there base class controls, but I would like them to use the style of there base class.  I am able to achieve this with the following xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type bc:DerviedClass}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type etk:BaseClass}}"/>
```

I would prefer not to use xaml so that the client programmer does not have to add this line to his xaml code. Is there a way to do this in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should consider Styling/Themeing using a Themes/generic.xaml file to style your custom control.

1. Things to keep in mind when using a generic.xaml:

   - Resource must be named generic.xaml and in a folder called Themes(case matters)
   - AssemblyInfo.cs needs a ThemeInfo attribute

     - [assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]

This theme will become the default whenever anyone used it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this:

```
Style s = (Style)derivedObj.FindResource(baseType);

if(s != null)
{
    Style derivedStyle = new Style(derivedObj.GetType(), s);
    derivedObj.Style = derivedStyle;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works if placed inside OnInitialized() method (doesn't work in constructor properly).  However, it is not applied in the designer. Any ideas?